# Почему не работает данный код?

Tags: javascript, массивы, rest, filter

Функция должна возвращать отфильтрованный массив из которого будут удалены дополнительные аргументы, передаваемые в функцию вместе с исходным массивом

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
let destroyTheArray = (arr, ...argsToRemove) => arr.filter(elem => !argsToRemove.includes(elem));  


}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // [1,1]
```

Comment: `argsToRemove` и где вы это определяете? не говоря уже о том, что вы просто определяете какую-то функцию внутри и не вызываете ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код работает. Просто функция `destroyer` ничего не возвращает.

Чтобы все заработало, эта функция вообще не нужна:

```js
let destroyTheArray = (arr, ...argsToRemove) => arr.filter(elem => !argsToRemove.includes(elem));

console.log(destroyTheArray([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)); // [1,1]
```

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, что именно не думает freeCodeCamp?

Comment: на SO  всё работает.. но удаляя на  FCC  лишнее,тесты данное решение не проходит почему-то,хотя на самом ресурсе есть абсолютно идентичное решение..

Comment: вот изначальный код,представленный там                                                                         function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, ну так проверяльщик ожидает функцию с именем `destroyer` просто переименуй переменную и все

Answer (score 0):

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  let arr1 = Array.from(arguments).slice(1);
  let d = [];
  
  for( let key of arr ){
   if( arr1.includes(key) ) continue
    d.push( key )
  }
 return d;
}

console.log( destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) ); // [1,1]
```

Comment: точно так же как в коде в вопросе: воспользоваться includes или indexOf